# get_post_meta not work in php foreach

Tags: post-meta, php

i have these codes :

```
foreach ( $ids as $idss ) {
echo  get_post_meta($idss, 'IMDB', true);
}
```

i have search box with Form element that search and find all id ( $ids ) of searched word .

i want to print all $ids 's IMDB field ! 
i can do it on page.PHP of theme ! 
but i cant do it on header.PHP

i used `global $post;`  and it didnot worked !

---

Updates ( answer ) :
i add this line to my code :

```
require_once( dirname(__DIR__) . '/wp-load.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your `$ids` array empty? Echo out each `$idss` to see if it contains a value.

```
foreach ( $ids as $idss ) {
  echo $idss . ' <-- ID<br>';
  echo  get_post_meta( $idss, 'IMDB', true );
}
```